# Building project with Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm new to jenkins and groovy and I'm trying to create my own configuration which allows me to build my project with various parameters. To achieve that I use Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter. As a Choice Type I set "Formatted HTML". It looks exactly as I want but unfortunately, no mater what, I cannot return parameters to build.

This is my groovy script:

```
if(useDefaultValues.equals("YES")) {
    return "defaultName"
 } else {
    inputBox = "<input name='name' class='setting-input' type='text'>"
    return inputBox
 }
```

[image: This is how my configuration looks]

[image: Build with default parameters]

[image: Build with other parameters]

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: On jenkins wiki I found some useful informations and rewrite my code. Now I return this:
'return "<input name=\"name\" value=\"${defaultName}\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">"'
But it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update your Groovy script to something like this:

```groovy
def defaultName = "default name"

if (useDefaultValues.equals("YES")) {
    return "<b>${defaultName}</b><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"value\" value=\"${defaultName}\" />"
 }

return "<input name=\"value\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">"
```

It's important that your input field uses name `value` - it does not change your parameter name, and if you named it `name` you will be able to access it as `$name` (if you use Groovy for instance).

It is also important that default value is passed as a hidden input field, otherwise parameter value is not set. This hidden input also has to use name `value`.

However there is one weird problem with HTML formatted input parameter - it always adds `,` in the end of the parameter value. So for instance if I pass `lorem ipsum`, when I read it with the parameter `$name` I will get `lorem ipsum,`. It looks like it treats it as a multiple parameters or something. To extract clean value from the parameter you can do something like (Groovy code):

```
name.split(',').first()
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about comma ( , ) . I thought I messed up some code. I was confuse with comma ( , ) everytime I use the parameter value from Formatted HTML.

Answer (score 5):

```
def defaultName = "default name"
if (useDefaultValues.equals("YES")) {
    return "<input type=\"text\" name=\"value\" value=\"${defaultName}\" />"
}
return "<input name=\"value\" type=\"text\">"
```

Check "Omit value field" fixed comma problem.([comma issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36806))